# loading fancybox on page load + specific options of fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I know the only way to trigger fancybox on page load is to simulate a click of a hidden link, however the problem is that it seems that this click launches the fancybox with the default options and not taking into consideration the options I've givem... For instance:

```
$("a.albumPhoto").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'modal' :   true,
     'onStart'  : function(){}
});

 $("#albumPhoto_1").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

I have links with class albumPhoto and the first image is with ID albumPhoto_1, so I trigger it automatically on page load as shown above. However the first image does not take the options mentioned above:

'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
'speedIn'       :   600, 
'speedOut'      :   200, 
'modal' :   true,
'onStart'   : function(){}
Does anybody know how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 $("#albumPhoto_1").trigger('click');
```

Because with the code you showed, you're calling the plugin again without options.
Hope this helps. Cheers